# typescript spread and cast at the same time in the function argument

Tags: typescript

is it possible in typescript to cast and spread function arguments at the same time?

here, I have an `Event` that in reality is an `UIEvent` that its `target` is pointing to the `document`.
so I need to cast Event to UIEvent so I can access the target.

the target is type `HTMLDocument` and needs to be casted to `document`

```
const scroll$ = fromEvent(document, "scroll");

const percentage = scroll$
  .pipe(map(
    ({target}:Document) //here I want to cast and spread a UIEvent
            => calculatePercentange(target.scrollingElement)))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

I tried

```
const scroll$ = fromEvent(document, "scroll");

const percentage = scroll$
  .pipe(map(
     (<UIEvent>({target}:Document)) //cast to any, then spread and then cast to document
            => calculatePercentange(target.scrollingElement)))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

so my question is there any way I do all the casting while I'm spreading the argument?

## playground

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-5nufde?file=index.ts

Comment: please share reproducable example

Comment: this example that I shard, just add rxjs to your workspace

Comment: @captain-yossarian added a stackblitz

Comment: Alternatively, you can cast target to Document into the `calculatePercentage` call: `calculatePercentage((target as Document).scrollingElement)`

Comment: @FrankBessou I can cast it out of the spread, just was curious how to do it inside the spread, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the event be of type `UIEvent & {target: Document}`. It will have properties of `UIEvent` and have its `target` correctly typed.

```js
const scroll$ = fromEvent(document, "scroll");

const percentage = scroll$
  .pipe(map(
     ({target}: UIEvent & {target: Document})
            => calculatePercentange(target.scrollingElement)))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

You can directly use this type as generic type parameter of `fromEvent` :

```js
const scroll$ = fromEvent<UIEvent & {target: Document}>(document, "scroll");

const percentage = scroll$
  .pipe(map(
     ({target})
            => calculatePercentange(target.scrollingElement)))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try next code:

```js
import { fromEvent } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";


function calculatePercentange(element: Element) {
    const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = element;
    console.log(scrollTop);
    // return (scrollTop / (scrollHeight - clientHeight)) * 100;
}

const scroll$ = fromEvent<Document>(document, "scroll");

const percentage = scroll$
    .pipe(map(
        (elem) => calculatePercentange(elem.scrollingElement)))
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

TS does not complain

Let me know if it works